Spring Data JDBC @Query method returning null when filtering on varchar2 column in Oracle DB
I am trying to setup connections to query a ready only database using Spring Data JDBC. My interface looks something like the following
@Repository
interface BaseRepository extends CrudRepository<DeliveryTask, String> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT DELIVERY_TASK_ID FROM DELIVERY_TASK WHERE ORDER_ID = :orderId")
    List<DeliveryTask> findByOrderId(@Param("orderId") String orderId);

}

My entity is defined as such
@Table("DELIVERY_TASK")
public class DeliveryTask {
    @Column("DELIVERY_TASK_ID") @Id
    String deliveryTaskId;

    @Column("ORDER_ID")
    String orderId;

    DeliveryTask(){}

    public DeliveryTask(String deliveryTaskId, String orderId){
        this.deliveryTaskId = deliveryTaskId;
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public DeliveryTask setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        return this;
    }
    public String getDeliveryTaskId() {
        return deliveryTaskId;
    }

    public DeliveryTask setDeliveryTaskId(String deliveryTaskId) {
        this.deliveryTaskId = deliveryTaskId;
        return this;
    }
}

The DELIVERY_TASK table has a PK DELIVERY_TASK_ID that is of type RAW. When I query on this field I am able to return results and the ORDER_ID is returned properly as well. When I query on ORDER_ID however, which is of type VARCHAR2, returns null.
The ORDER_ID I am querying for is a simple numeric string such as "123". This record definitely exists in the DB and submitting the query directly in other projects via plain java.sql does return results. I am left confused as to what the problem could be.
I have trace logs enabled and I can see this is what is printed
Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT DELIVERY_TASK_ID FROM DELIVERY_TASK WHERE ORDER_ID = ?]

Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [123], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12

Things I have tried:

Running the query with TRIM()

Running using LIKE instead of =

Reverting Java and JDBC driver versions


Oracle and dependencies version:

Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

Java  17 + ojdbc 11.21.9

spring-data-jdbc 3.3.0


I have also tried

Java 8 + ojdbc 8.21.3

spring-data-jdbc 2.3.3


Any insights will be appreciated as to why querying against this field in particular returns null.
EDIT
I do not have the necessary permissions to look at system tables on my account to see from DB side the query and parameters being submitted

Your query only returns the DELIVERY_TASK_ID you should be returning the ORDER_ID as well. Without that there is nothing to map. So either SELECT * FROM ...  or SELECT DELIVERY_TASK_ID, ORDER_ID FROM ...

You write: I am able to return results and the ORDER_ID is returned properly as well. How can this return the ORDER_ID when it is not part of the select list?
What does "select for" mean? It's part of the where clause? of the select clause?
Please, post the exact queries you are using, with the exact parameter values and the exact results. Is the result null or are fields of the result null?

Hi @JensSchauder. For clarification purposes I meant when I queried on ORDER_ID in the WHERE clause of the query I was returning null as the result.

Not a direct answer but some but a few hints about debugging this kind of situation assuming your problem is that a the where clause results in an empty result (now rows).
Try the following:

use a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate or JdbcTemplate
remove the parameter and make it a fixed part of the SQL statement
replace  = '123' with ` LIKE '%1%'
inspect the String you pass in as an argument in the debugger. Does it really only consist of the three digits 123?
inspect the value stored in the database. Check for example, that it has length three.


Thanks for the debugging hints. I was able to figure out the issue. Posted the RCA below.

The issue was this is a sharded DB. Initially, I was querying on another table that in the shard I was connected to had the data. I then erroneously assumed this record in the DELIVERY_TASK table existed in the same shard.
